# Is LINQ to Everything a good abstraction?

Tags: linq, performance, linq-to-sql, architecture

There is a proliferation of new LINQ providers. It is really quite astonishing and an elegant combination of lambda expressions, anonymous types and generics with some syntax sugar on top to make it easy reading. Everything is LINQed now from [SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) to web services like [Amazon](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/06/26/Introducing-Linq-to-Amazon.aspx) to [streaming sensor data](http://www.codeplex.com/Slinq/) to [parallel processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(VS.100).aspx). It seems like someone is creating an IQueryable`<T`> for everything but these data sources can have radically different performance, latency, availability and reliability characteristics.

It gives me a little pause that LINQ makes those performance details transparent to the developer. Is LINQ a solid general purpose abstraction or a RAD tool or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, LINQ is just a way to make code more readable, and hence more maintainable.  LINQ does nothing more than takes standard methods and integrates them into the language (hence the name - language integrated query).

It's nothing but a syntax element around normal interfaces and methods - there is no "magic" here, and LINQ-to-something really should (IMO) be treated as any other 3rd party API - you need to understand the cost/benefits of using it just like any other technology.

That being said, it's a very nice syntax helper - it does a lot for making code cleaner, simpler, and more maintainable, and I believe that's where it's true strengths lie.

Comment: "treated as any other 3rd party API" - I agree. Just a different interface :)

Comment: Yeah - LINQ is nothing but a (very nice) language-specific way to access a 3rd party interface.

Comment: I have come to believe that LINQ is largely about adding functional programming paradigms to C# and other previously purely OO languages in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as **similar** to the model of multiple storage engines in an RDBMS accepting a common(-ish) language of SQL, in it's design ... but with the added benefit of integreation into the application language semantics. Of course it is good!

I have not used it that much, but it looks sensible and clear when performance and layers of abstraction are not in a position to have a negative impact on the development process (and trust that standards and models wont change wildly).

**It is just an interface and implementation that may fit your needs**, like all interfaces, abstractions, libraries and implementations, does it fit?... **it is all the same answers**.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose - no.

LINQ is just a convenient syntax, but not a common RAD tool. In the big projects with complex logic I noticed that developers do more errors in LINQ that in the same instructions they could do if they write the same thing in .NET 2.0 manner. The code is produced faster, it is smaller, but it is harder to find bugs. Sometimes it is not obvious from the first look, at what point the queried collection turns from IQueryable into IEnumerable... I would say that LINQ requires more skilled and disciplined developers.

Also SQL-like syntax is OK for a functional programming but it is a sidestep from object oriented thinking. Sometimes when you see 2 very similar LINQ queries, they look like copy-paste code, but not always any refactoring is possible (or it is possible only by sacrificing some performance).

I heard that MS is not going to further develop LINQ to SQL, and will give more priority to Entities. [Is the ADO.NET Team Abandoning LINQ to SQL?](http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/is-adonet-team-abandoning-linq-to-sql.html) Isn't this fact a signal for us that LINQ is not a panacea for everybody ?

If you are thinking about to build a connector to "**something**", you can build it without LINQ and, if you like, provide LINQ as an additional optional wrapper around it, like LINQ to Entities. So your customers will decide, whether to use LINQ or not, depending on their needs, required performance etc.

p.s.
.NET 4.0 will come with dynamics, and I expect that everybody will also start to use them as LINQ... without taking into considerations that code simplicity, quality and performance may suffer.